# Edit my signature in PDF file in my iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad

In my iPad application I want to add signature in my pdf file.

I already do perform following steps:

1. Open pdf in UIView (zooming is not implemented yet).
2. Add one transparent subview (UIImageView) and draw signature on that.
3. Save all screen using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as a image.
4. Convert and save the image as a pdf.

This is works fine but pdf quality is very poor.

But now I want to add a signature/image as a pdf metadata. Same as a markup and commenting features of PDF.

Is there any help or sample code is available for the same?

Comment: Hey any one know any thing about the pdf editing in iOS. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to improve the quality of the output by skipping the image/pdf conversion, but afaik there's no lib that will help you editing the metadata of a pdf on the iPad (at least, none that's freely available).
Depending on what exactly you want to do, you may have to write a parser from scratch to know what exactly you have to append to your document to see the wanted effect:
It is very easy to append data to a pdf, but it has to be "registered" in the right locations so that a reader can use this information.

Comment: you wrote "It is very easy to append data to a pdf," but will you please elaborate how it is possible? any api or lib or framework available in ipone?